# SPDispose check gives error

Tags: feature-receiver

SPDispose gives error Disposable type not disposed Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite  ***This may be a false positive depending on how the type was created or if it is disposed outside the current scope when run with eleveted privilage is used.
here is the code:

```
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                SPWebApplication webAppContext = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWebApplication;

                site = webAppContext.Sites[0];
                userToken = site.SystemAccount.UserToken;
            });
            /* End: 003 */
            /* Start: 001 */
         using (SPSite siteColl = new SPSite(site.ID, userToken))
            {

                SPWebApplication webApp = siteColl.WebApplication;
                if (null != webApp)
                {
                    if (webApp.UpdateMappedPage(SPWebApplication.SPCustomPage.AccessDenied, Constant.customAccessDeniedPage))
                    {
                        webApp.Update();
                    }
                }
          }
```

Comment: Please provide us with some code. On which row are you getting this Error/Warning.

Comment: keeping site inside runWithElevated is not affecting anyway. stil gettin same error.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that this error is not from within the "using" part, but from the 
 site = webAppContext.Sites[0];
above.

Where is "site" appearing the first time? Do you really need this outside the elevatedPrivilegues-Part?

Comment: its the first time only. if i declare it inside elevatedPrivilages then it cant be identified inside using..:(

Comment: But if I see that right, you only need the ID. Why not save this in an extra variable and keep "site" inside the runElevated scope?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error generally comes when you have created an SPSite object and passed it to a function. The object is disposed inside the function and hence the calling function doesnt dispose the object. This error can also occur in the reverse condition where a function returns an SPSite/SPWeb object and the caller takes care of disposing of the object. Any other similar situations can also results with such errors.